# AngularJS ui-router to a state but use different URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my AngularJS application I want to catch errors and send the user to a 404 state like so:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateNotFound',  function(event, unfoundState, fromState, fromParams){ 
    //console.log(unfoundState.to);
    //console.log(unfoundState.toParams);
    //console.log(unfoundState.options);
    $state.go('404');
});
```

This is for when a user clicks a bad link (**e.g. has no state, as ones with states but no content are handled by the otherwise method**) in the app, etc.

The code loads the 404 state fine:

```
.state('404',
        {
            views: {
                'body': {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/404.html',
                }
            }
        });
```

But what I want to do is change the URL to the state they tried to access, so basically load the 404 state but use the incorrect URL (as a 404 would work in a server environment).

I've looked into doing:

```
history.replaceState(null, null, unfoundState.to);
$state.go('404');
```

But that causes major errors in the app and changes the URL but not the state!

How can I do this?

Comment: I have not tried. I'm not sure whether `$state.transitionTo('404',{},{location:false});` works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to catch all URLs not matching any of your previous routes :

```
.state("404", {
    url: "*path", // will catch all URLs
    templateUrl: 'partials/404.html'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state), I think you can do:

```
$state.go('404',{},{location:false});
```

Note: I'm in the process of creating a plunkr to verify but I don't have time to finish it up completely right now